# Replacement function for subset R

Tags: r, function

In R I'd like to write a function for changing the margins of a plot, without being forced to always enter all margins. I think replacement for subsets would be the way to go. But I can't figure out how to write the replacement function.

```
Mar <- function() par("mar")

`Mar<-` <- function (value) {
  par(mar=value)
}
```

So

```
Mar()[2:3] <- c(10, 5)
```

would be supposed to change the margins as:

```
x <- par("mar")
x[2:3] <- value
par(mar=x)
```

Getting the values is ok

```
Mar()
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
```

but trying to set results in an error:

```
Mar()[2:3] <- c(10, 5)
Error in Mar()[2:3] <- c(10, 5) : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Any ideas?

Ok, as Roland pointed out, we have no S3 class, so we can't overwrite the `[<-` function. Let's adapt that:

```
 Mar <- function() {
   structure(par("mar"), class="mar")
 }  

 `[<-.mar` <- function(x, ..., value){
   cx <- oldClass(x)
   class(x) <- NULL
   x[...] <- value
   class(x) <- cx
   par(mar=x)
   invisible(x)
 }
```

This works:

```
 > par("mar")
 [1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
 > mm <- Mar()
 > mm[2:3] <- c(10, 15)
 > par("mar")
 [1]  5.1 10.0 15.0  2.1
```

This does not:

```
 > Mar()[2:3] <- c(8, 9)
 Error in Mar()[2:3] <- c(8, 9) : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Subassignment is done with `[<-`. Your approach can't work.

Here is an alternative:

```
marassign <- function(direction, value) {
  mar <- par("mar")
  mar[direction] <- value
  par(mar = mar)
}

marassign(2:3, 5)
par("mar")
#[1] 5.1 5.0 5.0 2.1
```

Comment: Hmm really no way around that?

Comment: No, since `par` does not return an S3 object.

Comment: Ok, let's get a step further. Correct, we have no S3 object. Let's have one:  Mar <- function() {
  structure(par("mar"), class="mar")
}  
and now we should be able to define a `[<-.mar` <- function(x, ..., value){}, shouldn't we?